# File names with spaces in BASH

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write script that'll crop and resize large photos into HD Wallpapers.

```
#! /bin/bash


for i in `ls *.jpg`
do
    width=`identify -format '%w' $i`
    height=`identify -format '%h' $i`

    if [ `echo "$width/$height > 16/9" | bc -l` ]
    then
        exec `convert $i -resize 1920 -gravity Center -crop '1920x1080+0+0' +repage temp`
    else
        exec `convert $i -resize x1080 -gravity Center -crop 1920x1080+0+0 +repage temp`
    fi

    rm $i
    mv temp $i
done
```

But it seems that the script has problems with file names having spaces (like Tumble Weed.jpg). How can I fix this?

Comment: The answer has already been given below, but I'd just like to add that shell scripting is really bad for handling spaces in file names because so many lists are space-delimited - especially command arguments. Try copying a file with space via scp for example! It is nearly impossible without manual escaping.

Comment: You should read `http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls` in its entirety :-) it will improve drastically your bash skills

Comment: GNU coreutils added `ls --zero` (i.e., end each output line with NUL and not newline "\n")(as of 2022-06-11). See [ls source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First, you don't need `ls`.  By using `ls` in backtics, you implicitly make bash parse a string into a list, which splits by whitespaces.   Instead, make bash generate the list and separate it without such quirks:

Also, you need to enclose all `$i` usages into quotes, to make bash substitute it as a whole, not as a string split to separate words.

Here's the script that demonstrates both ideas:

```
for i in *.jpg ; do 
  echo "$i";
done
```

Comment: This does *not* always work and therefore is misleading. This always works. `SAVEIFS=$IFS;IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");for f in $(ls -lah);do echo "$f"
done;IFS=$SAVEIFS`

Comment: That helped, thanks, but I think it's missing a semicolon. This works for me: `SAVEIFS=$IFS;IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");for f in $(ls -lah);do echo "$f"; done;IFS=$SAVEIFS`

Answer (score 19):

Use read to circumvent the problem with spaces. It looks a bit unnatural to write the loop like this but it works better:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" | while read i
do
    # your original code inside the loop using "$i" instead of $i
done
```

with `-iname` you also get the jpg files that might have an extension with different casing like .JPG. "i" in "iname" means ignore casing.

Comment: As it is, this fails with names with literal backslashes, names with literal newlines, and names ending in whitespace.

Comment: To fix it, add a `-print0` to `find`, and make the shell end `while IFS= read -r -d '' i`; the `-r` fixes the backslashes, the `-d ''` and `-print0` fix the literal newlines, and the `IFS=` fixes support for names ending in whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to write the for-line like this:

```
for i in *.jpg
```

and encapsulate `$i` in double-quotes: `"$i"`.

---

If you insist on the

```
`ls *.jpg`
```

style, (if you for instance get your file-names from a more complex command) you could try setting `IFS` to `\n`:

```
IFS='\n'
```

Compare these two executions:

```
$ for f in `ls *`; do echo $f; done
hello
world
test

$ IFS='\n'; for f in `ls *`; do echo $f; done
hello world
test
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, use string replacement with `find`:

> `${string//substring/replacement}`
>   Replace all matches of `$substring` with `$replacement`.

so this works:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' | while read i ; do /bin/mv -f "$i" ${i// /_}; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes around file names. Like this:

```
width=`identify -format '%w' "$i"`
```

Please note the double quotes around `"$i"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #! /bin/bash 
 mkfifo ./lsOutput
 ls -1 *.jpg > ./lsOutput
    while read line  
    do 

    width=`identify -format '%w' "$line"` 
    height=`identify -format '%h' "$line"` 

    if [ `echo "$width/$height > 16/9" | bc -l` ] 
    then 
        exec `convert "$line" -resize 1920 -gravity Center -crop '1920x1080+0+0' +repage temp` 
    else 
        exec `convert "$line" -resize x1080 -gravity Center -crop 1920x1080+0+0 +repage temp` 
    fi 

    rm "$line"
    mv temp "$line"
 done<./lsOutput
```

Comment: Could use some explanation of streams and FIFOs .
I like that the read command  looks only for '\n' to get a string.