# How to deal with file name starts with spaces in bash?

Tags: bash

Normally, example shows usage like:

`for i in $(ls); do echo ${i}; done`

But if there is a file (or directory) named " screw", then the above line will give out wrong result.

How to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File names with spaces in BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967707/file-names-with-spaces-in-bash)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No please don't use/parse `ls`'s output. Use it like this:

```
for i in *; do echo "${i}"; done
```

Alternatively you can use `printf` (thanks to @ruakh):

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

Comment: You can still use `printf "%s\n" "$i"` in the for loop, for cases where an explicit loop is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS="$(echo -e "\b\r")";
for f in $(ls); do
    echo "$f";
done
```

In case you are forced to stick to parsing ls output (which you shouldn't)

Comment: Both backspace and carriage return, technically, are legal characters in file names (as are newlines, which this lets slip through), so one really shouldn't use `ls` like this, period.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use find with print

```
find ./ -print | xargs echo
```